# In Django how to convert a single page pdf from html template?

Tags: python, django, pdf

I am using `puppeteer_pdf` package to convert an HTML template into a pdf, but when my content increases, it creates another page in the pdf. I want the whole pdf as a single page.

My main goal is the make a jpg image from that pdf and send the image to the client. If there is another way to make a jpg image from HTML maintaining all CSS and images it will be very helpful.

This is my code :

```
import os
from puppeteer_pdf import render_pdf_from_template
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

def generate_pdf_invoice(invoice):
    context = {
        'invoice': invoice
    }
    output_temp_file = os.path.join(
        settings.BASE_DIR, 'static', 'temp.pdf')
    pdf = render_pdf_from_template(
        input_template='shop/invoice_email_pdf.html',
        header_template='',
        footer_template='',
        context=context,
        cmd_options={
            'format': 'A4',
            'scale': '1',
            'marginTop': '0',
            'marginLeft': '0',
            'marginRight': '0',
            'marginBottom': '0',
            'printBackground': True,
            'preferCSSPageSize': False,
            'output': output_temp_file,
            'pageRanges': '1-2',

        }
    )
    filename = 'test.pdf'
    # return pdf
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf;')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename='+filename
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a possibility with imgkit to render to png or jpg

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import imgkit

# render template to html string
context = { .... }
rendered_html = render_to_string('template.html', context)

# html string to image
options = {
    'format': 'png',
    'width': 670,
    'disable-smart-width': ''}
imgkit.from_string(rendered_html, 'target_filepath.png', options=options)
```